# Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC") Not Working. ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, intellij-idea, classpath

I am trying to load/register the JDBC driver so I can use SQLite and it was working in NetBeans but I can't seem to get it to work in IntelliJ. I've spent far too long on this issue, so any help is appreciated.

I navigated File/ProjectStructure/Modules and then clicked on the dependency tab and clicked add Jar File. I then added the "sqlite-jdbc-3.19.3.jar" file

My code doesn't seem to be able to locate the class:

```
import org.dreambot.api.script.AbstractScript;
import org.dreambot.api.script.Category;
import org.dreambot.api.script.ScriptManifest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

@ScriptManifest(category = Category.WOODCUTTING, name = "Mulitbox", author =     
"Computor", version = 2.0)
public class Main extends AbstractScript {

private Connection conn;
private Statement stmt;

@Override
public int onLoop() {

    try {
        log("inDB");
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); // Register the JDBC Driver - Step 2
        // Establish Connection. Create Database if none exists else connect to existing one - Step 3
        // url a database url of the form *  <code> jdbc:<em>subprotocol</em>:<em>subname</em></code>
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:userDB.db");
        stmt = conn.createStatement(); // Create statement - Step 4s

        stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTS (USERNAME TEXT);"); // Execute SQL Statement



    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log("test SQLException" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        log("test ClassNotFound");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
}
```

This is how my project directory looks: 
[image: Screen 1]

This is what I did to add the jar file to the project:
[image: Screen 2]

This is what the output looks like: (It is suppose to loop because it's in the onLoop() block)

```
Script set to Running!
inDB
test ClassNotFound
inDB
test ClassNotFound
inDB
test ClassNotFound
inDB
test ClassNotFound
```

EDIT 7/12/2017 6:18PM:

I don't have a ClassNotFound Exception anymore. I solved it by adding the SQLite .jar file like the picture I posted and then going into Artifacts and right clicking the SQlite .jar file and selecting Extract into output root. Then select the Include in project build checkbox. Then it should work.

But now my connection doesn't work. `conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:userDB.db");` 
When I retrieve the message from the thrown exception, it gives: `Error Opening Connection`

Comment: It may be the error of the IDE, please try to restart IDE or your computer. Refer to [the similar problem](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208382565-org-sqlite-JDBC-will-not-be-found) with you here

Comment: @TuyenNguyen  I have restarted the IDE, should I completely reinstall it?
I too have seen that post before.

Comment: Let's check the jar file if it included the class before you tried to reinstall the IDE. Because may be the jar broken

Comment: It says `e.printStackTrace()`, where is the stacktrace?

Comment: When you run/debug this, is the sqllite jar included in the classpath arguments in the output in intellij console? - Should be the very first line in console

Comment: I'm thinking this might be related to the framework this script is run in. The framework probably runs just the script, and does not use the classpath of the project in IntelliJ. See this issue: https://dreambot.org/forums/index.php/topic/7948-connecting-to-mysql-database/#entry71625

Comment: @NickL Because of the framework It's built in, I'm not sure I have access to the traditional console. I use their "Debugger" for logs.

Secondly, I checked out the post you linked me too and am messaging the guy that had the problem to see if it was ever resolved.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't think I can show the stack trace, the client I run the code in only allows me to use their "log". I have to do e.getMessage() where e is the exception thrown